# GCM push notification throttling (requests frequency)

Tags: curl, request, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How many requests per minute can I send to Google's GCM service to avoid throttling my messages?
I can't find any concrete number..

Can I send 1k per minute? 5k? 10k?

Answer (score 0):

They don't give numbers in the documents, but it appears the throttling that exists is for the frequency of sending messages to the same device. So if you are sending messages to a large number of devices, there is no info about any throttling that may or may not take place.

> To prevent abuse (such as sending a flood of messages to a device) and
>   to optimize for the overall network efficiency and battery life of
>   devices, GCM implements throttling of messages using a token bucket
>   scheme. Messages are throttled on a per application and per collapse
>   key basis (including non-collapsible messages). Each application
>   collapse key is granted some initial tokens, and new tokens are
>   granted periodically therefter. Each token is valid for a single
>   message sent to the device. If an application collapse key exhausts
>   its supply of available tokens, new messages are buffered in a pending
>   queue until new tokens become available at the time of the periodic
>   grant. Thus throttling in between periodic grant intervals may add to
>   the latency of message delivery for an application collapse key that
>   sends a large number of messages within a short period of time.
>   Messages in the pending queue of an application collapse key may be
>   delivered before the time of the next periodic grant, if they are
>   piggybacked with messages belonging to a non-throttled category by GCM
>   for network and battery efficiency reasons.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling)

Answer (score 0):

We have been implementing system for sending GCM pushes and we never had issues with throttling messages and currently we are sending ~500k messages/minute from 1 server (using many threads).

We had some issues with quota, but contacting Google and increasing it solved issue.

Mateusz

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks for response! I have an issue with only 20% successful delivery sending much less messages..

Comment: How do you know if the message haven't been delived due to throttling?  I face some problems that the GCM Doesn't pass all my messages from device to server (with payload)